# GET-parameter into controller Yii 2

Tags: php, get, yii2

Can I pass GET-parameter into controller action when I click on a link?

Controller action:

```
public function actionFilter() {
    $categoryId = Yii::$app->request->get('id');

    return $this->render('index', compact('categoryId'));
}
```

Link:

```
<?= Html::a('Horror', ['site/filter'], [
        'data' => [
          'method' => 'get',
          'params' => [
            'id' => 'horror',
          ],
        ]
]); ?>
```

In HTML link seems like:

```
<a href="/bs/web/index.php?r=site%2Ffilter" data-method="get" data-params="{"id":"horror"}">Horror</a>
```

Action controller don`t calling. With POST-request it works correct.

Comment: 1 )  have you tried  with Yii::$app->request->queryParams ?  2) why you don't use normal assing in url  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
<?= Html::a('Horror', ['site/filter', 'id' => 'horror']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple call  for both

```
<?= Html::a('Horror', ['site/filter', 'id' => 'horror']); ?>
```